# passing commandline argument within vbscipt

Tags: vbscript

I am looking to create a script where I will accept the input from the user, pass it to command line as parameter and display the result.

Something like:

```
Dim WshShell, Return,sctask,arg

arg=inputbox("Enter the computername")
Set arg = Wscript.Arguments
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run("C:\schtasks /query /s &arg")
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what [Ekkehard.Horner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17670892/1630171) said: you can't append a collection (`WScript.Arguments`) like a simple string:

```
Set arg = Wscript.Arguments
...
WshShell.Run "C:\schtasks /query /s " & arg
```

You need to re-build the argument string like this:

```
ReDim args(WScript.Arguments.Count-1)
For i = 0 To WScript.Arguments.Count-1
  If InStr(WScript.Arguments(i), " ") > 0 Then
    args(i) = Chr(34) & WScript.Arguments(i) & Chr(34)
  Else
    args(i) = WScript.Arguments(i)
  End If
Next

WshShell.Run "C:\schtasks /query /s " & Join(args, " ")
```

Also, there usually isn't a `schtasks` executable in `C:\`.

Answer (score 1):

Re:

```
WshShell.Run("C:\schtasks /query /s &arg")
```

(1) VBScript does not interpolate variables, you have to concatenate the content of `arg` (properly):

```
WshShell.Run "C:\schtasks /query /s " & arg
```

(WRT @Ansgar's posting: I assume `arg` holds the computer name (hopefully) optained by

```
arg=inputbox("Enter the computername")
```

and that your next line:

```
Set arg = Wscript.Arguments
```

was added by the copy-&-paste-goblin)

(2) You must not use param list () when calling a sub/not receiving a return value. So either use the above line or

```
iRet = WshShell.Run("C:\schtasks /query /s " & arg)
```

Re: display the result

As `.Run` just executes the command and returns a status, the least cost/most gain method to get the output of `schtasks` is `.Exec`:

```
Option Explicit

Dim oWSH : Set oWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim sCmd : sCmd     = "schtasks /Query /S winxpsp3"
Dim sRes : sRes     = oWSH.Exec(sCmd).Stdout.ReadAll()
WScript.Echo sRes
```

Use the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to learn how to improve my demo snippet - a production ready version should do some error handling.

If you don't want to use `.Exec`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4963209/603855) for sample code that uses `.Run` and re-direction to get the command's output.