# Passing Arguments to PowerShell

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I am using following Sub to pass arguments to Powershell.

```
     Sub testpower()
      Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
      WshShell.Run ("Powershell.exe -file .\test.ps1 -path ""Shell.txt"" ")
     End Sub
```

But,the output is not generated when run in VB,but if try to run directly from run command,it gives the desired result.Please  help.

test.ps1 script:

```
 Param([String]$path)
    Get-AuthenticodeSignature $path | Out-File  "C:\Documents and Settings\acmeuser1\output.txt"
```

Comment: have you tried to use the full path names of the file?

Comment: Yes,i tried both ways..

Comment: that's a bit strange as it worked for me. Is the C:\Documents and Settings\acmeuser1\output.txt file created after you run the script? have you tried to output something else to it other than the output of the Get-AuthenticodeSignature?

Comment: I was making a mistake its working for me now..I want to change the value of the path everytime ,which is "Shell.txt" in this case.how?

Comment: This is what i want to do now..Sub testpower()
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
k = Chr(34) & "C:\Documents and Settings\acmeuser1\1.vbs" & Chr(34)

'filepath = "" & "C:\Documents and Settings\acmeuser1\1.vbs" & ""
WshShell.Run ("C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe -file test.ps1 -path k ")

End Sub

Comment: I could be mistaken about the error but it looks like you're going to pass a relative path that resolves to the PS Install directory... I understand that k is supposed to be a variable but in the context shown above, you're going to most likely get k as your path, because it wasn't passed as "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -File "<FullPs1Path>\Test.ps1" -Path k. Keep in mind this all needs to have the same quoting in your script -- the example is the necessary command line. For the PowerShell exe, you won't need the quotes, though.

Answer (score 0):

This question is essentially answered in [VBscript code to capture stdout, without showing console window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919573/vbscript-code-to-capture-stdout-without-showing-console-window) - there are several techniques there that are stated as working. To summarize, use `WShell.Exec` instead of `WShell.Run`, and then capture the output via `WShell.StdOut.ReadLine()` or `WShell.StdOut.ReadAll()`.