# howto pass procesname parameter to powershell form vbs script

Tags: powershell, vbscript, parameters

If have created a VBS script that watches for new created processes like notepad.exe or calc.exe. When a new notepad or calc proces is found i like to do something in powershell with the found procesname.

The VBS script i created works fine when I manually edit the procesname in the VBS file, but when i try to use/pass the procesname form vbs (strName) to powershell I expect to see the procesname (notepad.exe), but instead the powershell window shows "strName".

I've been all over the internet to find a solution, without result.

---

### My VBS file [start.vbs]

source: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/11/02/hey-scripting-guy-november-1-2009.aspx

```
arrProcesses = Array("calc.exe","notepad.exe")
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
i = 0

Set colMonitoredProcesses = objWMIService. ExecNotificationQuery _        
("Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 5 Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'")

Do While i = 0
Set objLatestProcess = colMonitoredProcesses.NextEvent
strProcess = LCase(objLatestProcess.TargetInstance.Name)
For Each strName in arrProcesses
    If strName = strProcess Then


''Run Powershell file
'source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156178/passing-arguments-to-powershell

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

''this works great
WshShell.Run ("Powershell.exe -file .\GetParamFromVBS.ps1 ""notepad.exe"" ")

'this doesnt
WshShell.Run ("Powershell.exe -file .\GetParamFromVBS.ps1 ""strName"" ")

'OR
'Trying to work arround it, with no result :(
RUNPSVAR="(" + """" +"Powershell.exe -file .\GetParamFromVBS.ps1 & """"" +strName +"""""" +""& " " +"""" +")"
wscript.Echo RUNPSVAR

WshShell.Run ("Powershell.exe -file .\GetParamFromVBS.ps1 ""RUNPSVAR"" ")

    End If
Next
Loop
```

---

### My Powershell File [GetParamFromVBS.ps1]

source: [How to pass command-line arguments to a PowerShell ps1 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293907/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-powershell-ps1-file)

```
param($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4)
$Script:args=""

write-host "Num Args: " $PSBoundParameters.Keys.Count

foreach ($key in $PSBoundParameters.keys) {
$Script:args+= "`$$key=" + $PSBoundParameters["$key"] + "  "
}
write-host $Script:args

pause
```

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
WshShell.Run("Powershell.exe -file .\GetParamFromVBS.ps1 ""strName"" ")
```

To:

```
WshShell.Run("Powershell.exe -file .\GetParamFromVBS.ps1 '" & strName & "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables aren't string literals.

So something like this

```
a = "a string literal" & aVariableContainingAString
```