# Execute a hidden process to retrieve the output, without creating a textfile?

Tags: vbscript, exec, output, wsh, powercfg

I'm trying to execute a hidden process to retrieve the output.

For this task I'm trying to use [Exec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method but the problem that I see is that I can't hide the process window?.

I've seen an alternative way using [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method to start the process hidden, and then writting the output to a textfile, and then parsing the text content, but **that It's not what I'm looking for** 'cause I always try to avoid bad programming practices in other languages so I would like to know if this operation in VBS can be performed without managing the creation of external text files, just I want to simplify things and don't create textfiles.

Here is my code:

```
Response = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"). _
           Exec("powercfg.exe /GetActiveScheme"). _
           StdOut.ReadAll

PowerPlanName = Split(Split(Response, "(")(1), ")")(0)
PowerPlanGUID = Split(Split(Response, ":")(1))(1)

Msgbox "Information about the current energy scheme."  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
       "Name: " & PowerPlanName                                    & vbNewLine & _
       "GUID: " & PowerPlanGUID,                                                 _
       64,                                                                       _
       "Energy scheme (powercfg.exe)"

WScript.Quit(0)
```

Comment: Why would you think that capturing command output in a temporary file is a bad practice? It's not.

Comment: see if you can live with http://stackoverflow.com/a/4963209/603855

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Run, Exec does not allow you to hide the window.

> Exec Method:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a(v=vs.84).aspx
>
> Run Method:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx

However, capturing data in a temp file isn't a bad practice. In your case, using Run and dumping into a temp file is probably your best option with what you're trying to do.