# VBS Run cmd.exe output to a variable; not text file

Tags: vbscript

This is what I have so far.  It works; outputing the folder path to temp to a text file.
What I really want, is to output the data to a variable.  Every example I see online, show how to do this using something like:

```
set objScriptExec = wshShell.Exec (strCommand)
```

followed by

```
strresult = LCase(objScriptExec.StdOut.ReadAll. // code
```

I want this to run with `Run`, not `Exec`, because I want the command prompt windows to be hidden as I will performing many commands with the code below.  How can I capture that output to a variable?

```
Set wsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCommand = "cmd /c echo %temp% > %temp%\test.txt"
wsShell.Run strcommand,0,True
```

Comment: I'm sure youve already looked into this, but why not store in a text file, read the text file, then delete it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690134/running-command-line-silently-with-vbscript-and-getting-output

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/a/4963209/603855

Answer (score 3):

This may be done with the Windows Script Host Exec command. StdOut, StdIn, and StdErr may all be accessed, and ERRORLEVEL is available when the command completes.

```
Dim strMessage, strScript, strStdErr, strStdOut
Dim oExec, oWshShell, intErrorLevel
Dim ComSpec

Set oWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ComSpec = oWshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%comspec%")

intErrorLevel = 0
strScript = ComSpec & " /C echo %temp%"

On Error Resume Next
Set oExec = oWshShell.Exec (strScript)
If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
  strMessage = "Error: " & Err.Message
  intErrorLevel = 1
Else
  Do While oExec.Status = 0
    Do While Not oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
      strStdOut = strStdOut & oExec.StdOut.ReadLine & vbCrLf
    Loop
    Do While Not oExec.StdErr.AtEndOfStream
      strStdErr = strStdErr & oExec.StdErr.ReadLine & vbCrLf
    Loop
    WScript.Sleep 0
  Loop
  intErrorLevel = oExec.ExitCode
  strMessage = strStdOut & strStdErr & CStr(intErrorLevel)
End If

WScript.Echo (strMessage)
```

NOTE: Replacing "ReadLine" above with "Read(1)" accomplishes the same thing, but adds an ability to process characters rather than whole lines.

Answer (score 2):

Of course `Wscript.Shell` would be a lot easier, but, since you want more fine grain control of your session, consider using `Win32_Process`. Usually, one uses this to control the placement of a new window, but, in your case, you want it hidden, so I set `startupInfo.ShowWindow = 0` which means `SW_HIDE`. The following declares a `VBScript` function called `RunCmd` and which will run a command in an invisible window saving the output to a text file and then return the contents of the text file to the caller. As an example, I invoke `RunCmd` with the `HOSTNAME` command:

```
Function RunCmd(strCmd)
  Dim wmiService
  Set wmiService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
  Dim startupInfo
  Set startupInfo = wmiService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")
  Dim fso
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim cwd
  cwd = fso.GetAbsolutePathname(".")
  startupInfo.SpawnInstance_
  startupInfo.ShowWindow = 0
  ' startupInfo.X = 50
  ' startupInfo.y = 50
  ' startupInfo.XSize = 150
  ' startupInfo.YSize = 50
  ' startupInfo.Title = "Hello"
  ' startupInfo.XCountChars = 36
  ' startupInfo.YCountChars = 1
  Dim objNewProcess
  Set objNewProcess = wmiService.Get("Win32_Process")
  Dim intPID
  Dim errRtn
  errRtn = objNewProcess.Create("cmd.exe /c """ & strCmd & """ > out.txt", cwd, startupInfo, intPID)
  Dim f
  Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("out.txt", 1)
  RunCmd = f.ReadAll
  f.Close
End Function

MsgBox RunCmd("HOSTNAME")
```

References:

- [Create method of the Win32_Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Win32_ProcessStartup class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I wanted to stay clear from making txt files.  Would have thought there would be a way to output to variable instead of txt file.